# MySQL Natural Language Search Stopwords behavior, still shows results despite stop word?

Tags: mysql

So I have a MySQL database that has a table of names of companies. For example

```
AES Corp
```

I put in my stopwords.txt

```
Corp
```

Yet when I do a fulltext search it still returns results like this,

```
select * from companies where MATCH(listOfCompanies.name) AGAINST('AES Corp');

SHANGHAI FOREIGN TRADE CORP. PU D
GFT USA CORP. 
GFT USA CORP. 
QET, CORP. 
FUN-4-ALL CORP.
```

Shouldn't it not return any of those results because I filtered out Corp so therefore it's only trying to match on AES? Or am I misunderstanding how the full text search works?

Comment: What is `AGAISNT`? Is that your actual query??!! I very much doubt it...

Comment: Uh yes that is the actual query...the results are what are actually returned as well. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html Clarified OP that it is using Natural Language Search.

Comment: You've spelled a MySQL keyword wrong; it should be `AGAINST` not `AGAISNT`.

Comment: Sorry I did not copy paste directly, the query is correct, I just can't type :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood the `AGAINST` keyword. Look at the sample query provided on that very page you've linked -- the keyword comes up in both of the resulting rows. `AGAINST` does not filter out results with the specified keyword(s), but rather does quite the opposite -- looks through the specified columns to ensure there is a match: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: I answered my question myself as I made a really dumb mistake but just to clarify with you, IF a word in the AGAINST() query is in the stopwords.txt, it should IGNORE that word right? That's how I understood the purpose of stopwords.txt but as I am a SQL noob you may know more about the inner workings that I do.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I did wrong and it is a very embarrassing mistake. The search actually works as configured, I just was using a script to parse and upload data and it was using an UPDATE so it did not actually REMOVE old results. I should have emptied the table and let it repopulate.